# Facebook Feed Dialog does not work on Chrome/Android native app

Tags: facebook, google-chrome, user-interface, dialog, feed

I am developing a Facebook Canvas App which allows user to post a link to their wall:

```
function postFeed(){
    FB.ui({
      method: 'feed',
      link: 'https://apps.facebook.com/?????',
      name: '?????',
      description : '?????',
      picture: '?????',
    }, function(response){});

}
```

It works fine on desktop (all browsers including desktop Chrome) and mobile Firefox. However **when I use mobile Chrome or Android Facebook App's internal browser to open it, the following message shows up when I run `postFeed()` and be redirected to the feed dialog:**

```
An error occured. Please try again later.
API Error Code: 110
API Error Description: Invalid user id
Error Message: Missing user cookie (to validate session user)
```

`postFeed()` is called after I run the following code:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
           alert("Welcome!");
        }
}, {scope: 'public_profile'});
```

However if I remove the above code, the error message disappears and I can see the feed dialog normally.

Is there any possible reasons/solution that can solve the problem but without removing the above code?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Using the dialog to post does not require any permission; so why would you want to force users to login to your app first anyway? That just creates additional friction, and might deter people from making a post in the first place.

Comment: Sorry that I have simplified some code. The part under if (response.authResponse)  is actually much more complicated, including user submitting a form with access token in order to verify if user is a Facebook user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use `'share'` instead of `'feed'` method and the problem is gone.